# Writing formula to calculate gift card balances

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a database of Gift card numbers, with each transaction associated with each number. Some have no charges, some have up to 5 or 6. I need to come up with a formula to say:

If a card number matches another on in this column, calculate the charges on the corresponding row in the "charges" column. I have tried variation of the SUMIF function and am getting results, but not the ones i want. One of the main issues is that the card number cell is part of the range being scanned. so it's ALWAYS recognizing itself.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

EDIT: I am sorry. The current method i am trying is: =SUMIF(D2:D30895,A2=A2:A30895)

[Screenshot of formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7A5V.png)

The whoever said the issue is related to range was correct. Because the A2, in this case, is in the A column, it's picking up on itself. I have also tried If-Then statements, however those have all ended in disaster.

EDIT 2: Using the suggested formula of: =SUMIF($D$2:D2,A2,A$2:A2) and dragging it down resulted in all zeros as the result. I have a small range and an exaple of where you can see cards that should have a balance, but the formula reads 0. I know this is an oddly specific request and i appreciate any and all help.

[Range with new formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPQ6T.png)

EDIT 3: Undid previous Edit. Moved to Pivot Table and most of the data is doing exactly what I need. Some of the cards with multiple transactions are not calculating correctly. I have included one screenshot with 3 separate pages.

1-Main Raw Data
2-Pivot Table "error"
3-new table made by clicking on pivot table row.

[Pivot Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGgVB.png)

Comment: It would be helpful to see some sample data and exactly what it is you have tried so far.

Comment: a shot in the dark, I think you have a range issue. You need to anchor at the top, bottom of your range would be the row of the transaction (not the whole table). So each transaction the formula is actually expanding...

Comment: Share some sample data along with Formula you have tried so far will hep us to fix the issue!!

Comment: I have made edits to the original post. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Good job on your edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, and now that you have given an example, change your formula in row 2 to:

```
=SUMIF($D$2:D2,A2, A$2$:A2)
```

The $ anchors the top of the formula, now drag the formula down and you'll see the formula expanding, so in row 35 you should see:

```
=SUMIF($D$2:D35,A35, A$2$:A35)
```

Let me know if this isn't doing it.

----EDIT-----------

Please note that this formula style assumes dates are in chronological order (as if you are adding a new row to the bottom of the sheet each time someone uses a giftcard). If the data isn't ordered then a pivot table would be the preferred method.

Comment: My answer above computes a running balance, but a pivot table on your data can do the same thing, or if you exclude dates, it would give you the balance. Depending on what you are really looking for, the pivot may be a more understandable format...

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the assistance. Unfourtunitly, it's not quite working 100% yet. It's pullingf all zeros. I have a screenshot that i will add to the main post showing an example of it. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: In playing around with the formula, it doesn't seem to be doing exactly that i need it to. It's not scanning the column for matches and ONLY combining those values for the balance. 

That seems to be the part that is throwing off the formula.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention my formula only works if the data criteria is in date order. I'll edit my answer to note that. If you can't reorder the date column, then the pivot table is the best option.

Comment: Alright, I sorted them by date and pushed the formula, but i am still getting zeros. I am going to start investigating the pivot table method. I am not familiar with it, but I will start digging in. Thank you so much for all of your help. I truly appreciate it. 

I made a new edit, with the new screens shot.

Comment: OK, you were right. This is exactly what i needed! I am having one weird issue, but i am 85% of the way there. Some of the rows are not calculating the sums in a proper format. I am not sure if the multiple rows are causing an issue, however, I can't seem to find any sort of consistency in the issue. 

I have made a new edit with the most current information.

Comment: I figured it out as soon as i commented. How do i select your answer as the correct one? I did not see an option to mark you are the person with the correct solution. THANK YOU so much for taking the time.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, I just pointed you in a direction. But when you do have time play around with the pivot table.